# 17.04 Wireless dropping randomly on Intel 8265 / 8275

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, intel-wireless

I installed xubuntu on a new Thinkpad the other day, and can connect to my dual band home router (Netgear R7000) fine (both 5g and standard), but the connection drops every few minutes. I've gotten by reconnecting to my network manually, but it's annoying and I'd like to not have to do that. I mostly don't know where to start, having tried a few other solutions here or elsewhere to no avail. Any direction would be much appreciated!

```
uname -sr
Linux 4.13.5-041305-generic

lspci | grep Wireless
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)

sudo lshw -class network                             
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 78
       serial: f8:34:41:da:85:27
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.5-041305-generic firmware=22.391740.0 ip=192.168.1.118 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:281 memory:ed100000-ed101fff

sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager                                                                           
-- Logs begin at Thu 2017-10-12 21:06:37 MDT. --
Oct 12 21:25:29 COMPUTER NetworkManager[6012]: <info>  [1507865129.7537] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Oct 12 21:25:29 COMPUTER NetworkManager[6012]: <info>  [1507865129.7538] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Oct 12 21:25:29 COMPUTER NetworkManager[6012]: <info>  [1507865129.7554] device (wlp4s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Oct 12 21:25:29 COMPUTER NetworkManager[6012]: <info>  [1507865129.7557] device (wlp4s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Oct 12 21:25:29 COMPUTER dhclient[7023]: bound to 192.168.1.118 -- renewal in 38150 seconds.
Oct 12 21:25:29 COMPUTER NetworkManager[6012]: <info>  [1507865129.7561] device (wlp4s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Oct 12 21:25:29 COMPUTER NetworkManager[6012]: <info>  [1507865129.7561] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Oct 12 21:25:29 COMPUTER NetworkManager[6012]: <info>  [1507865129.7594] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Oct 12 21:25:29 COMPUTER NetworkManager[6012]: <info>  [1507865129.7594] policy: set 'NETWORKNAME-5G 1' (wlp4s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Oct 12 21:25:29 COMPUTER NetworkManager[6012]: <info>  [1507865129.7598] device (wlp4s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
```

Things I've tried:

- Setting a BSSID in Network Manager
- Adding `wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no` to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
- Disabling ipv6 in`/etc/sysctl.conf` with:

  `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
  net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
  net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1`

Update 1 - Still having difficulty after trying @chili555 's suggestions(thanks!). I tried the following and made sure to reboot after each step.

- Turned off power saving in network manager and tlp
- set REGDOMAIN=US in /etc/default/crda
- removed spaces from SSID
- stopped using the 5GHz 802.11a/n/ac network in favor of the 2.4GHz b/g/n one
- turned off 20/40hz coexistence in my router settings
  changed channel from auto to 1
- set wifi security to WPA2-PSK [AES].

Would Mbps mode affect me? As of now it's Up to 600 Mbps and Up to 1733 Mbps for the 2.4/5g networks respectively.

Update 2 - Tried a fresh 17.10 install and had the same issues, so I can only assume it's a driver issue or router issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest that you turn off power saving in Network Manager. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Next, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Finally, we notice that the name of the SSID is NETWORKNAME-5G 1. If there is really a space in the name of the SSID, I recoomend that it be changed to something like  NETWORKNAME-5G_1; that is, without a space.

After these changes, reboot the router and the computer and let us know if there is any improvement.