# Wireless drops randomly after getting new router

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, 17.10, intel-wireless

Recently I changed old router which supported 802.11 n only to Linksys EA8500 which supports 802.11 ac and mu-mimo. (my laptop supports mimo as well)
But after my laptop connected to 802.11ac, the ping drops every 5-10 mins for few mins.
So I tried everything on [17.04 Wireless dropping randomly on Intel 8265 / 8275](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964477/17-04-wireless-dropping-randomly-on-intel-8265-8275)
But I still have a problem.

And this is profile.

```
    su@suputer:~$ lspci | grep Wireless
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
su@suputer:~$ sudo lshw -class network  
[sudo] password for su: 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 78
       serial: f8:63:3f:15:a5:e5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-16-generic firmware=31.532993.0 ip=192.168.1.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:127 memory:d1100000-d1101fff
su@suputer:~$ 
su@suputer:~$ sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager 
-- Logs begin at Tue 2017-10-31 11:25:42 CDT. --
Oct 31 14:11:16 suputer NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1509477076.0693] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
Oct 31 14:11:16 suputer NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1509477076.0695] device (wlp1s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
Oct 31 14:11:16 suputer NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1509477076.0697] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Oct 31 14:11:16 suputer dhclient[6307]: bound to 192.168.1.101 -- renewal in 38401 seconds.
Oct 31 14:11:16 suputer NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1509477076.0829] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Oct 31 14:11:16 suputer NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1509477076.0833] policy: set 'Guesswhatthepasswordis_5GHz' (wlp1s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Oct 31 14:11:16 suputer NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1509477076.0842] device (wlp1s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Oct 31 14:15:44 suputer NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1509477344.4856] connectivity: (wlp1s0) timed out
Oct 31 14:26:42 suputer NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1509478002.3300] device changed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:01:00.0/net/wlp1s0, iface: wlp1s0)
Oct 31 14:26:42 suputer NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1509478002.4490] device changed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
```

It will be appreciated if anyone gives me suggestions!
Thanks

P.S. I am currently using 17.10 
also I have never problem on wireless at work but only at home.
I suspect there is something wrong on firmware but not sure tho and how to deal with that.

```
su@suputer:~$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    2.067813] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.084281] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-33.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.084441] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-32.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.090128] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 31.532993.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.117978] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    2.176551] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: f8:63:3f:15:a5:e5
[    2.272924] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
su@suputer:~$ ls -l /lib/firmware
total 86548
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   27156 Oct  4 08:46 1a98-INTEL-EDK2-2-tplg.bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 3com
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root    4096 Sep 20 15:31 4.10.0-35-generic
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 4.13.0-16-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Oct  4 08:46 a300_pfp.fw -> qcom/a300_pfp.fw
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Oct  4 08:46 a300_pm4.fw -> qcom/a300_pm4.fw
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 acenic
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 adaptec
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 advansys
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   50698 Mar 29  2017 agere_ap_fw.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   65046 Mar 29  2017 agere_sta_fw.bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   20480 Oct 29 02:06 amdgpu
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 ar3k
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  153416 Mar 29  2017 ar5523.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   95500 Mar 29  2017 as102_data1_st.hex
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   81820 Mar 29  2017 as102_data2_st.hex
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 asihpi
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root    4096 Apr 11  2017 ath10k
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  246804 Oct  4 08:46 ath3k-1.fw
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    4096 Apr 11  2017 ath6k
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 ath9k_htc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 atmel
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   35180 Oct  4 08:46 atmel_at76c504_2958.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   39928 Oct  4 08:46 atmel_at76c504a_2958.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    9726 Mar 29  2017 atmsar11.fw
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 atusb
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 av7110
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root    4096 Oct 31 14:48 backport-iwlwifi
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 bnx2x
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 brcm
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   13388 Mar 29  2017 carl9170-1.fw
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 carl9170fw
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 cavium
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  412528 Mar 29  2017 cbfw-3.2.1.1.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  414016 Mar 29  2017 cbfw-3.2.3.0.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  414480 Mar 29  2017 cbfw-3.2.5.1.bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 cis
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     107 Mar 29  2017 configure
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 cpia2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  582440 Mar 29  2017 ct2fw-3.2.1.1.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  583688 Mar 29  2017 ct2fw-3.2.3.0.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  584216 Mar 29  2017 ct2fw-3.2.5.1.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  655436 Mar 29  2017 ctefx.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  537160 Mar 29  2017 ctfw-3.2.1.1.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  538712 Mar 29  2017 ctfw-3.2.3.0.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  539144 Mar 29  2017 ctfw-3.2.5.1.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    4120 Mar 29  2017 ctspeq.bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 cxgb3
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 cxgb4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 dsp56k
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   18643 Mar 29  2017 dvb-fe-xc4000-1.4.1.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   12401 Mar 29  2017 dvb-fe-xc5000-1.6.114.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   16497 Mar 29  2017 dvb-fe-xc5000c-4.1.30.7.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   33768 Mar 29  2017 dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    8128 Mar 29  2017 dvb-usb-it9135-01.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    5834 Mar 29  2017 dvb-usb-it9135-02.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   50222 Mar 29  2017 dvb-usb-terratec-h5-drxk.fw
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 ea
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 edgeport
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 emi26
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 emi62
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 ene-ub6250
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 ess
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  180776 Mar 29  2017 f2255usb.bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 go7007
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   32900 Oct  4 08:46 hfi1_dc8051.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   16848 Mar 29  2017 hfi1_fabric.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   33296 Sep 12 11:27 hfi1_pcie.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    5360 Mar 29  2017 hfi1_sbus.fw
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct  8  2016 hp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   72684 Mar 29  2017 htc_7010.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   50980 Mar 29  2017 htc_9271.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1251036 Mar 29  2017 i2400m-fw-usb-1.4.sbcf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1334532 Mar 29  2017 i2400m-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1531932 Mar 29  2017 i6050-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 i915
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 imx
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 intel
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   12288 Oct 29 02:07 intel-ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  209190 Oct  4 08:46 ipw2100-1.3.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  201138 Oct  4 08:46 ipw2100-1.3-i.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  196458 Oct  4 08:46 ipw2100-1.3-p.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  191154 Oct  4 08:46 ipw2200-bss.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  185428 Oct  4 08:46 ipw2200-ibss.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  187836 Oct  4 08:46 ipw2200-sniffer.fw
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 isci
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  337520 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  337572 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  689680 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  701228 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  695876 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  707392 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  609892 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  683996 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  688616 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  918212 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-3160-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  918268 Jun  8 11:48 iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  670484 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  667284 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  669872 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1384856 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-3168-21.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1028092 Aug 17 11:29 iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1032436 Oct  4 08:46 iwlwifi-3168-27.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1036372 Oct  4 08:46 iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  150100 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  187972 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  340696 Jun 27 09:57 iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  337400 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  454608 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  444128 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  677296 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  679436 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  469780 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  672352 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  782300 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  786920 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1049284 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1049340 Jun  8 11:48 iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  683236 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  679780 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  680508 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  736844 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  880604 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  885224 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180356 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180412 Jun  8 11:48 iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  690452 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  697828 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode -> iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1002800 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1008692 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1384500 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1383604 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1385368 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1028376 Jun  8 11:48 iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1032740 Oct  4 08:46 iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1036528 Oct  4 08:46 iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1745176 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2351636 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2394060 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2227284 Oct  4 08:46 iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2309768 Oct  4 08:46 iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2389968 Mar 29  2017 iwlwifi-8265-21.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1811984 Jun  8 11:48 iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2234528 Oct  4 08:46 iwlwifi-8265-27.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2303024 Oct  4 08:46 iwlwifi-8265-31.ucode
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 kaweth
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 keyspan
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 keyspan_pda
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 korg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  118888 Mar 29  2017 lbtf_usb.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     262 Mar 29  2017 lgs8g75.fw
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 libertas
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 liquidio
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 matrox
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 mellanox
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 moxa
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 mrvl
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   45412 Mar 29  2017 mt7601u.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  368220 Mar 29  2017 mt7650.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   81908 Sep 12 11:23 mt7662.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   26350 Sep 12 11:23 mt7662_rom_patch.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   13847 Mar 29  2017 mts_cdma.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14067 Mar 29  2017 mts_edge.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   13847 Mar 29  2017 mts_gsm.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   13769 Mar 29  2017 mts_mt9234mu.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   13769 Mar 29  2017 mts_mt9234zba.fw
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 mwl8k
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 mwlwifi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  378832 Mar 29  2017 myri10ge_eth_big_z8e.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  389144 Mar 29  2017 myri10ge_ethp_big_z8e.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  389056 Mar 29  2017 myri10ge_ethp_z8e.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  378736 Mar 29  2017 myri10ge_eth_z8e.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  536192 Mar 29  2017 myri10ge_rss_eth_big_z8e.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  545936 Mar 29  2017 myri10ge_rss_ethp_big_z8e.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  545920 Mar 29  2017 myri10ge_rss_ethp_z8e.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  536176 Mar 29  2017 myri10ge_rss_eth_z8e.dat
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 netronome
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   15664 Oct  4 08:46 NPE-B
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   15664 Oct  4 08:46 NPE-C
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 nvidia
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 ositech
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1845305 Mar 29  2017 phanfw.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  463612 Mar 29  2017 qat_895xcc.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  114176 Mar 29  2017 qat_895xcc_mmp.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  265444 Mar 29  2017 qat_c3xxx.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  114820 Mar 29  2017 qat_c3xxx_mmp.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  398144 Mar 29  2017 qat_c62x.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  114820 Mar 29  2017 qat_c62x_mmp.bin
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Mar 29  2017 qat_mmp.bin -> qat_895xcc_mmp.bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 qca
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 qcom
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 qed
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   76802 Mar 29  2017 ql2100_fw.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   84566 Mar 29  2017 ql2200_fw.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  125252 Mar 29  2017 ql2300_fw.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  136038 Mar 29  2017 ql2322_fw.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  265300 Sep 12 11:28 ql2400_fw.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  275128 Sep 12 11:28 ql2500_fw.bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 r128
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    9452 Mar 29  2017 r8a779x_usb3_v1.dlmem
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    9416 Mar 29  2017 r8a779x_usb3_v2.dlmem
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    9416 Mar 29  2017 r8a779x_usb3_v3.dlmem
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   36864 Oct 29 02:06 radeon
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    1684 Sep 12 11:23 README
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 rockchip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      63 Mar 29  2017 rp2.fw
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 rsi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   94100 Mar 29  2017 rsi_91x.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    8192 Mar 29  2017 rt2561.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    8192 Mar 29  2017 rt2561s.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    8192 Mar 29  2017 rt2661.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    8192 Sep 12 11:28 rt2860.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    8192 Sep 12 11:28 rt2870.bin
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      10 Mar 29  2017 rt3070.bin -> rt2870.bin
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      10 Mar 29  2017 rt3090.bin -> rt2860.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    4096 Jun 27 09:57 rt3290.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    2048 Mar 29  2017 rt73.bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 RTL8192E
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 rtl_bt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 rtl_nic
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 rtlwifi
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Mar 29  2017 s2250.fw -> go7007/s2250-2.fw
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Mar 29  2017 s2250_loader.fw -> go7007/s2250-1.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  352652 Mar 29  2017 s5p-mfc.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  306312 Mar 29  2017 s5p-mfc-v6.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  343756 Mar 29  2017 s5p-mfc-v6-v2.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  382724 Mar 29  2017 s5p-mfc-v7.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  360576 Mar 29  2017 s5p-mfc-v8.fw
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 sb16
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 scripts
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     816 Mar 29  2017 sdd_sagrad_1091_1098.bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 slicoss
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 sun
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 tehuti
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   13765 Mar 29  2017 ti_3410.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   13764 Mar 29  2017 ti_5052.fw
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 ti-connectivity
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 tigon
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 ti-keystone
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   51972 Mar 29  2017 tlg2300_firmware.bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 ttusb-budget
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 ueagle-atm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 usbdux
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     999 Mar 29  2017 usbduxfast_firmware.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    1770 Mar 29  2017 usbdux_firmware.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    8192 Mar 29  2017 usbduxsigma_firmware.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   16382 Mar 29  2017 v4l-cx231xx-avcore-01.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  141200 Mar 29  2017 v4l-cx23418-apu.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  158332 Mar 29  2017 v4l-cx23418-cpu.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   16382 Mar 29  2017 v4l-cx23418-dig.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  262144 Oct  4 08:46 v4l-cx2341x-dec.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  376836 Oct  4 08:46 v4l-cx2341x-enc.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  155648 Oct  4 08:46 v4l-cx2341x-init.mpg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   16382 Mar 29  2017 v4l-cx23885-avcore-01.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   16382 Mar 29  2017 v4l-cx25840.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    8192 Oct  4 08:46 v4l-pvrusb2-24xxx-01.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    8192 Oct  4 08:46 v4l-pvrusb2-29xxx-01.fw
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 vicam
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   11341 Mar 29  2017 vntwusb.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4082928 Sep 12 11:28 vpu_d.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  131160 Sep 12 11:28 vpu_p.bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 vxge
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    4947 Oct  4 08:46 WHENCE.ubuntu
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   23554 Mar 29  2017 whiteheat.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    5626 Mar 29  2017 whiteheat_loader.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    3588 Aug 17 11:09 wil6210.brd
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  350748 Aug 17 11:09 wil6210.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   97824 Mar 29  2017 wsm_22.bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 yam
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 yamaha
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   62484 Oct  4 08:46 zd1201-ap.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   70612 Oct  4 08:46 zd1201.fw
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 29 02:06 zd1211
```

Comment: How is the mode set in the 5 gHz segment? I recommend a/n/ac mixed. After making any changes, reboot the router.

Comment: I see, that will help me but in case of that I could not take a advanatage of fast wireless :'(

Comment: It should connect at n speeds and, if the wireless card and the router agree, negotiate up to ac speeds. That is exactly how it works for *my* Intel device. In any event, the card is unusable now, right? Have you tried it to see if it works?

Comment: I realized that the mode as mixed. But it won't help. I am going to try n or ac only to test. Also I set WPA2 Personal only so that I can avoid any additional problem. But it is weird since I have 3 laptops 2 are 2indows 10 tho. But both work fine.